# how to unit test grpc method using moq and nunit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, grpc

I am trying to test out my grpc client side code which sends an authentication request to the server.

In the constructor of the class, i have:

```
 Channel channel = new Channel(adr, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
 client = new MessageService.MessageServiceClient(channel);
```

and the method inside that class that i want to test is:

```
public void LogIn(String username, String pass)
        {
            try
            {
                String encryptedPass = StringEncrypt.Encrypt(pass, cPP, cSA, "SHA1", 2, cIV, 128);
                Response res = client.LogIn(NewAuthRequest(username, encryptedPass));
                if (res.Authenticated)
                {
                    loggedIn = true;
                    user.UserId_ = username;
                    sess.Sessionid = res.Sessionid;
                    sess.Userid = username;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Login request response: " + res.Authenticated);
            }
            catch (RpcException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("RPC failed " + e);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

loggedin, user and sess are class variables.

i read up on how to test void methods so i was thinking of running this method in the unit test and asserting if after the method has been run, if the values of loggedin, user and sess have been changed like they should have. but i am confused about how to create moqs. StringEncrypt is a static class and the client is created using one of the grpc generated files. and i remember reading somewhere u can only create moqs of abstract classes/interfaces... so how can i create moqs for them?

thanks!!

Comment: not really related to grpc, it's more about how to do unit testing in general. For the grpc specific part: you can override (or mock) the client.LogIn method to return a fabricated response so that the test is hermetic. After running the method, you can check your assertions about the state change.  You can also refactor your code so it's easier to unit test.  There is no way to mock  StringEncrypt.Encrypt directly (as it is a static method), but you can change your code so that the Encrypt is called by another method and mock that one.